# Password with FirstOrCreate

Tags: laravel

I want to use FirstOrCreate for a new user.

Like that:

```
$user = User::FirstOrCreate([
        'name' => $request->username,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => User::generatePassword()
    ]);
```

generatePassword() just generate a random 8 chars string string.

Thing is is doesn't work because it's looking for a user that has this password value.

So, it works when there is no user with this email, but when there is it gives me a constraint error.

What should be the cleanest way to fix it???

Comment: why would you use `password` field while searching? Users should be able to search by email and username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a grammatical error. `::firstOrCreate` searches based on criteria provided, and if it's not found, it will create the database entry and return the model with that data. `::firstOrNew` does that *without* saving the model automatically.

So, you would want this.

```
$user = User::firstOrNew([
    'email' => $request->email,
]);
```

We do not include `name` or `password` because we are not checking to see if Josh with josh@stackoverflow.com using password foobar123 exists, we just want to know if josh@stackoverflow.com has an account.

Your controller logic seems a bit weird because we would first want to validate that information *before* creating a model, but I'll roll with it.

```
$user = User::firstOrNew([
    'email' => $request->email,
]);

// This model does not have a DB record.
if (!$user->exists)
{
    $user->name = $request->username;
    $user->password = User::generatePassword();
    $user->save();
}

return $user;
```

With that logic, we find a record based on email. If the record exists, we pass it. If it does not, we assign it a username and generate a password for it before creating the record and then pass it.